# Как задать select из 2 связанных таблиц с условием?

Tags: mysql, sql

есть 2 связанные таблицы в phpmyadmin: **general(g_id)** и **prosroc(g_id)**.

В таблице general есть колонка: пол(муж/жен).
с помощью select-а были отобраны из таблицы prosroc **n**-ое кол-во **g_id**.

Теперь необходимо сделать примерно следующий запрос:

отобрать те **g_id**, из тех **n**-ое кол-во отобранных, у которых верны условия:
у этих **g_id** в general **пол=муж(или жен)**

Как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте соединение таблиц:

```
select *
from (тут ваш запрос в виде select ... from prosroc where ...) t
    join general g on g.g_id = t.g_id
where gender = 'муж' /* gender = 'жен' */
```

Comment: спасибо, получилось)